# Hbase state=PENDING_OPEN after altering the table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I had an issue with my Hbase (CDH4). I wanted to add a column family in the table.
But the installation had been done without snappy compression.
But i accidentally copy pasted the script which had mentioned SNAPPY COMPRESSION.

I Disabled the table and then altered the table. It showed me that the table has been altered.
Now when i tried to enable the table again it says **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotDisabledException**

When i try to disable it says: **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotEnabledException**

I saw the HbaseMaster UI. It is showing the regionserver for the table as :

> TABLE,,1350624529725.05b804a85c63beef408e8795e85e6a5c.
>   state=PENDING_OPEN, ts=Tue Apr 23 10:49:02 IST 2013 (945s ago),
>   server=XXXHOSTNAME

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is but I two things that may work are

1. try to see if hbck can fix it (`hbase hbck -fix`)
2. try to install
   snappy (`yum install snappy` and then also copy snappy jars to the
   hbase lib dir)

Comment: I tried the "hbck", it did not help. I had to manually delete the table entry from the .META. in order to delete the Ghost table.